# Is it possible to update the model from the database in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have an app that uses a NodeJS server and a Python background worker, I'm using SQLAlchemy for database access on the python side.

My problem is that I intend to manage the database from the Node app, and the python side just need to have its model/metadata updated from time to time, I looked into alembic but I found that the `alembic revision --autogenerate` command does the opposite of what I want, it generates the migration so that the database can be synchronized with the model, but I want to do the opposite, I want to synchronize the model based on the database, is that possible with alembic or another tool?